# ng-bind not updating, only after refreshing the page

Tags: angularjs, apply, watch, ng-bind

Using `$resource` to get the data, the pages have the data from the previous page until I refresh it. I've read that it's because angular itself doesn't know that it's been updated. However even after using $watch and `$applyAsync`, it doesn't work. (`$apply` gives me a digest error).

```
angular.module('app.factory',[])
  .factory('teamService', ['$resource','$routeParams',function($resource, $routeParams){
        return $resource('/api/team/:id', {id: $routeParams.id},{
          update: {
            method: 'PUT'
          }
        });
      }]);

(function(){
  angular.module('app.team',[])
  .controller('TeamController',['teamService','$scope','$rootScope','$resource',function(teamService,$scope,$rootScope, $resource){

      $scope.teamid = teamService.query();
```

Comment: @Kalamarico that's not quite accurate. $resource methods return empty array or object reference that gets populated when request completes

Comment: @charlietfl how do I tell $resource that a request is made? The only way it works currently is by refreshing the page

Comment: try passing the id in from controller instead

Comment: @charlietfl what/Which id?

Comment: @charlietfl Oh I see what you're saying.I'll try that

Comment: what is teamService.query(), in side the service there is no such function

Comment: @AliAdravi teamservice is the name of the factory

Comment: I said where is you query() function???

Comment: @AliAdravi: it returns a $resource. It has .query() by default.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good to me, so I think this is a routing issue. Maybe you could try resolving the resource in the router and not in the controller. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

I would also try assigning when the promise resolves:

```
teamService.query().$promise.then(function (result) {
    $scope.teamid = result;
}
```

And to force a digest you could try $timeout instead of $apply. ($timeout needs to be injected into the controller.) $apply gives an error if called during a digest, $timeout waits until the current digest has completed (it still uses $apply internally).

```
teamService.query().$promise.then(function (result) {
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.teamid = result;
    });
});
```

Sorry, not a real answer - the comment box is so limited at times.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. And now I get a 404 error. But I think this is the right track and will keep working on it. Thanks!